# Stale enter inputs being fed into password

Tags: python

I am having the following problem where the user keeps pressing "enter key" on the command window when the python script is running...following is what runs on the command window,but user keeps pressing enter which eventually gets fed into password and the script fails,how do I prevent this?

```
 Parsing the XML

 Building the build combo table

  **Password: //asks for password but user had multiple enter key presses above which is taken as passoword and fails**
```

Python code:-

```
url='http://wiki.com/'+wikiName+'/w/index.php?title='+hId +'_'+rId+'&action=edit'
cookiehand = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(user=getpass.getuser(),passwd=getpass.getpass(),uri=authhost,realm=realm)
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler, cookiehand)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# make the request
req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    txt = f.read()
    f.close()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    txt = ''
    print 'An error occured connecting to the wiki. No wiki page will be generated.'//eventually gets this error
```

Comment: can anybody help me answer this query please?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is validate the input. Something like this:

```
user = ""
pass = ""

while not user and not pass:
    user = getpass.getuser()
    passwd = getpass.getpass()
```

Note that this won't work if blank passwords are allowed. If you have control over the getpass library, it might make more sense to move the validation inside those two methods, and perhaps make them optional with a default argument like `validate=False`